# Very basic database design (total beginner)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I just started learning server-side programming (PHP) and I'd like to try to make a simple application that uses a MySQL Database to store some users' data (like notes).
I'm a total noob in databases and I don't know how to link account information (username, password etc.) to its data.

What do you think is the best approach to design a database like that? (I thought I could create a table with account information and then a table for each user with its data, or just one big table, but I really know nothing about structuring a database).
What's the best way to do that? This will be just a test application, but I'd like to know also something that will work efficiently in a big application with many users.

Thanks.

Comment: While I respect that you're a beginner, you'll receive better help if you demonstrate a basic understanding or show what you have tried with specific questions. As it stands, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple note application you should create two tables to store the information, "users" and "notes". Then on your code process the whole user input and query it into those tables. Notice how on the "notes" table you have a "user_id" field, that's where you link your notes with the "id" field from the "users" table when selecting or inserting queries.

Here's an example of how your database should look like.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This site has a lot of useful information that could get you started on PHP.
 [Practical PHP Programming](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp)

Comment: You'll also want to learn about things like password hashing and salts because you would never want to store a password in plaintext. And then, you'll probably want to just use a user authentication library for PHP so that you don't get it wrong, and endanger any user information on a public website :)

Comment: Wouldn't you want `user_id` in the `notes` table to be an `int`, not a `varchar`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Bert. I made a typo. Make sure the user_id is int(11) instead of varchar(255).

Answer (score 0):

You start by looking at the structure of your data.  In the example you've given, assuming a user could have multiple notes, you would create a user table and a note table.  Each would have an indexed (and unique) ID field.   The Note table would have a UserID field that matched the ID in the User table.

You should really search for introductory database design tutorials; experience is the only way you will become good at this.

Answer (score 0):

One big table is something you only do to address performance issues. The cost is data duplication, a potential for poor data integrity and database designers thinking you are not very good at it.

Nowhere near enough information to give you a suitable design and it wouldn't realy help unless you understood why it was suitable.

You need to find a tutorial on normalisation, at last up to 3NF (third normal form)

Based on what you've said which is a tad confusing

One table to hold user information, with at least a UserID
Then an other related table (assuming a user can have more than one note)
Called UserNotes, with at least NoteID and the UserID.

Can't really help more than that, google a tutorial. Learn just sql (MySQls flavour first), before you go near PHP, there are loads of tutorials on that as well. Look for one that uses PDOs.